# Replacing space with backslash and space

Tags: linux, shell

When I execute:

```
varx=$(echo "a  b"|sed -r -e "s/\s/\\\ /g"); echo $varx
```

The output will be:

```
a\ \ b
```

But when I execute the following script with the argument `"a  b"` (folder `a  b` exists):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
target=$(echo ${1} | sed -r -e "s/\s/_/g")
source=$(echo ${1} | sed -r -e "s/\s/\\\ /g")
mv ${source} ${target}
set +x
```

The output will be:

```
++ echo a b
++ sed -r -e 's/\s/_/g'
+ target=a_b
++ echo a b
++ sed -r -e 's/\s/\\ /g'
+ source='a\ b'                       1) question
+ mv 'a\' b a_b                       2) question
mv: target ‘a_b’ is not a directory
+ set +x
```

3 questions:

1) Why `source='a\ b'` and not `'a\ \ b'` ?

2) Why `mv 'a\' b a_b` and not `mv 'a\ b' a_b` according to the previously calculated `source` value?

3) And how to force the script do the same that the command line version does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add double quotes to  `$1`:

```
source=$(echo "${1}" | sed -r -e "s/\s/\\\ /g")
target=$(echo "${1}" | sed -r -e "s/\s/_/g")
echo mv \"${source}\" \"${target}\"
```

In your script, the `echo` command process `a` and `b` as parameters. With double quotes, `$1` is not splitted.

To illustrate :

```
$ echo one     two
one two
$ echo "one     two"
one     two
```

Comment: More generally, any variable which contains a file name should always be double-quoted.  See further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: Thank you. The final solution was not to use "source" variable at all so that the script looked so:

target=$(echo "${1}" | sed -r -e "s/\s/_/g")
mv "${1}" "${target}"